# Saving dataframe in scala intellij throws exception

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying to load a CSV or an XML File using Intellij Spark Scala into a pre-existing hive table and then it gives below exceptions on the last step while saving dataframe.

### Ironically: the code below works fine in spark-shell without any issues with all four cases.

### 1. when I use Hive Context and Insertinto().

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
println("CONFIG DONE!!!!!")
val xml = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","employee").load("/PUBLIC_TABLESPACE/updatedtest1.xml")
println("XML LOADED!!!!!!")
xml.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("designation").insertInto("test2")
println("TABLE SAVED!!!!!!!")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, boolean, int, boolean, boolean, boolean)

### 2.when I use Hive Context and SaveAsTable().

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
println("CONFIG DONE!!!!!")
val xml = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","employee").load("/PUBLIC_TABLESPACE/updatedtest1.xml")
println("XML LOADED!!!!!!")

xml.write.format("parquet")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy("designation")
  .saveAsTable("test2")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, boolean, int, boolean, boolean, boolean)

### 3. when I use SQL Context and Insertinto().

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new SQLContext(sc)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
println("CONFIG DONE!!!!!")
val xml = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","employee").load("/PUBLIC_TABLESPACE/updatedtest1.xml")
println("XML LOADED!!!!!!") xml.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("designation").insertInto("test2")
println("TABLE SAVED!!!!!!!")
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: test2;

### 4. when I use SQL Context and saveAsTable().

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new SQLContext(sc)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
println("CONFIG DONE!!!!!") 
val xml = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","employee").load("/PUBLIC_TABLESPACE/updatedtest1.xml")
println("XML LOADED!!!!!!") xml.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("designation").saveAsTable("test2")
println("TABLE SAVED!!!!!!!")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Tables created with SQLContext must be TEMPORARY. Use a HiveContext instead.

***EDITED WITH BUILD.SBT file:***

```
BUILD.SBT File: name := "testonSpark"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.0"
```

Comment: Could you check if you are able to print first row or row count of xml right after loading it ?

Comment: Employee: [Technical Lead,1,Satish Kumar]
Employee: [Testing,2,Ramya]

Comment: This is the output that I have got when I print the data after loading it.

Comment: Are you submitting jar file to spark-submit.

Comment: Yes exactly. That is why I am writing code in Intellij

Comment: When you run the 4 cases in spark shell, where is your spark shell running? In a hadoop ecosystem, like MapR, Cloudera, etc or locally ?. Where does your Hive service is running ? locally or in cluster ?

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh could you upload your **build.sbt** file as well

Comment: Hi Dumitru, I am writing only one case at a time on intellij and running spar submit command.

Comment: Done Ankush please check the edited part

Comment: try add `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0"` as well in sbt

Comment: Interesting case...if `com.databricks.spark.xml` worked for you I'd say that the `build.sbt` is not correct. Can you `sbt run` and see what errors you get?

Answer (score -1):

**Try with sbt file as**

```
val sparkVersion = "1.6.0"
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "apache-snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/"
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion
)
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0"
```